# Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is my problem: I have a large form/checklist that I would like to make digital for ease of use.

Thoughts: I would like to use existing tools that would be easy to integrate. My first option is Access 2010.

My question: I would like to enter the questions into a database and then use those entries to auto generate a form that can be used to allow the user to input the actual data into the database. An example would be I have 11 Sections of questions and under each section I have sub-sections that can contain anywhere from 1-... how many every questions we need.

Is it possible to use data stored in an Access database to generate a form with Checkboxes that can be used to input data?

Please point me in the right direction. Obviously there is the option of just creating multiple forms or one big form, but I would like this form to easily be changed etc... Less work more automation.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Your question is very broad and thus not intended for SO. You don't even specify if you would like to keep everythig into access, making it a Windows applications with underlying access file for data storage, or even a web application.

Comment: I clearly stated I wanted to use Access 2010. Therefore I would like to keep everything in Access. Thanks

Comment: @Alex, you can use Access as just the front-end while storing the data somewhere else (SQL Server for example). That would give you the flexibility of Access as a front-end tool while keeping the data secure. I would recommend this if you don't want users to have easy access to everyone else's responses.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the requirements of your project, this may be quite possible.  If you want to use Access as both the back-end and front-end, then you'll need to work within a few limitations:

1. Because Access combines the user interface and design interface into the same screen, it requires a certain amount of trust that the user can't or won't try to get too creative with changing the data, seeing everyone else's data, changing the design of your form because they are bored, etc. There are ways around these problems, but they can get complicated.
2. Will all your users be using Window's machines with Access 2010 installed and with the original default settings?  If so, good.  If not, there may be ways that this could still work.
   (There's more, but that's all I can think of right now)

To get started, here's a broad outline:

1. Make a table for your questions. This table would just have the questions.
2. Make a form using that question table as the source. Leave the checkboxes and other answer fields unbounded.  Include a 'submit' button at the bottom.
3. The submit button will create a sql query to insert the user's answers into a 2nd table.

If you have any specific questions, we here at SO will be glad to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to dynamically and easily change the number of questions in the sections, what I would do is:

In the main Questions table, add a field called Section to allocate the questions into diffferent ones, and another one Yes/No field to select those that are included (you may also exclude them by leaving the section field empty, as you wish). This will solve the problem of changing the design easily. you probaly will need an admin form in order to do this changes, to avoid touching the tables directly, but this is your decision.

Secondly, in order to allow the users to efectively answer the generated form, you have to ask yourself if you want to accumulate the answer sets, and if you are going to control who answers